# Suppose $g$ is even and let $h=f \circ g$. Is $h$ always an even function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I came across one of the following problems in my homework set:

$$ \text{Suppose} \, g \, \text{is even and let} \, h=f \circ g. \text{Is} \, h \, \text{always an even function?}$$

I came to the conclusion through examples that "yes" the answer was true. Rather than just random examples, I also tried thinking about in different way. If we have a function $f$ and we compose it with $g$ and perform the even function test then the even function, $g$ will always evaluate to itself and which makes entire function equivalent. For example, let $g$ be $x^2$ and let $f$ be $\sin x$ then $f \circ g$ is $\sin (x^2)$ and $f(x) = f(-x)$ because $\sin (x^2) = \sin ((-x)^2)$.

Is my second approach better than my first? Is there a different and more concrete way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Anupam's answer cleanly covers your question; as an additional exercise, you might try answering the analogue: "Suppose $g$ is an odd function and $f$ is an arbitrary function, and let $h=f\circ g$.  Is $h$ always an odd function?"

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sorry if my question was not very clear. I already knew I was right because I checked the answers and I had a few examples to support my answer. What I am looking for is _another_ way to approach the problem and solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on a concrete-as-can-be proof of the assertion:

"Let $h$ be the composition $f\circ g$.  Then by the definition of even function, $h$ is an even function if $h(-x) = h(x)$ for all $x$.  Since $g$ is specified as an even function, we have that $g(-x) = g(x)$ for all $x$; therefore, since one property of a function is that $x=y\implies f(x)=f(y)$, by substitution we have $f(g(-x)) = f(g(x))$ for all $x$.  But written in terms of the composition $h$, this is the statement that $h(-x) = h(x)$ for all $x$; in other words, that $h$ is an even function."

This is essentially your argument made concrete; while various steps could be taken to put it into more formal proof syntax, this should be good enough for all intents and purposes.  You can be more concrete than this (e.g., this could be turned into a truly *formal* proof, one that could be verified by a theorem prover), but it's difficult to really imagine a *different* approach to the problem that wouldn't be worse; all this one uses are the relevant defining properties of 'function' and 'even function'.

As I mentioned in a comment, I encourage you to try and perform the analagous proof for the assertion that "if $g$ is an odd function and $f$ an arbitrary function, then $h=f\circ g$ is an odd function"; is the statement true or false, and why?  If the statement is false, can you find conditions on $f$ to make it true?  Working through this may give you a better sense for how to use these definitions in formal proofs.

Comment: Thanks! I will certainly look into the question you have posed. I'm assuming it's going to be more difficult to prove :).

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Looking at your proof I understand `h`  should be even . But initially I considered the example $g(x)=x^2, f(x)=\sqrt x$. Then $h(x)=x$. So isn't h odd? Where have I gone wrong in the chosen example?

Comment: @clarkson It isn't the case that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ for negative $x$ - by the usual definition of $\sqrt{}$ (as the positive square root), you have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, which is an even function.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are right. $f\circ g(-x)=f(g(-x))=f(g(x))=f\circ g(x)$ always.

Comment: right to the point.